# UIButton goes to the starting point of animation when title is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm animating a button to be moved for some distance when pressed. After it travels that distance, it should change its title and stay at that position. However, when the animation is over it jumps back to the starting point and changes it's title. When the same code is run without button changing it's title, it works fine. So it seems that

```
self.button.setTitle("hehehe", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

is causing the problem.
This is the code:

```
//when button pressed
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.button.center.y -= 50
        }) { _ in

            self.button.setTitle("hehehe", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
```

Comment: You should use constraints to do layout changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to do the animation using constraints instead. First, Set up a trailing (for instance, depends on how you wish to animate) like so:

[image]

I named mine **myConstraint**:

[image]

Once you have these two IBOutlets:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

You can do the animation and change the text like so (I placed this code in the button action):

```
// Animate
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.myConstraint.constant = // the new "length" of the constraint, just test different numbers to understand it
            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { _ in
            self.myButton.setTitle("hehehe", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
```

Comment: great! that solved the problem.  Could you explain why my previous code didn't work?

Comment: the AutoLayout system will set the view to its original position as the constraints aren't updated. Constraints are the correct way to animate :)

Comment: ou. so when button's title is changed, that calls some AutoLayout's method to set the constraints. Funny fact, if I set the buttons title to the one it allready has, the code runs without any problem. thanks, you helped a lot!

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1,disable autolayout of this button**
In viewDidLoad add and it will work

```
self.button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

**Option 2**,animate constraints as **Erik** said

Comment: Option1 works great! I used it in this way: signInButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true